# Can I use Spyro (figure series 1) for Skylanders Giants?

Tags: skylanders-giants

Can I use Spyro (figure series 1) for Skylanders Giants (3DS)? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://skylanderscharacterlist.com/getting-started/figure-compatibility/):

> Over the years Activision has put out charts trying to explain Figure Compatibility. The simple fact of the matter is though that Figure Compatibility can no longer be explained through a simple chart.
>
> With that being said, do not despair. There is just one simple rule you have to learn to solve the mystery of Figure Compatibility. You just have to answer one simple question and you will be able to figure it all out on your own.
>
> **In which game did _________ have his Series 1 figure?**
>
> Then you know that the Skylander figure in question is compatible with that game and every game after.

Also, from [this chart](http://www.gamestop.com/gs/pages/landing/skylanders-compatibility/), Spyro is playable in Skylanders Giants.